# Trying to use existing mysql to communicate with new snipe-it container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So I'm trying to setup a new container that needs to communicate with mysql. I setup the mysql container. I did a

`docker network ls`

to see the name of the network it uses. When I start the snipe-it container using

`docker run -d -p 8082:80 -p 443:443 --name="snipeit" --network=mysql_default --mount source=snipe-vol,dst=/var/lib/snipeit --env-file=./snipe-it-env snipe/snipe-it`

When going to the web portal of the docker container I get a message from the setup script saying it can't connect to the db. To update the settings in the .env file.
As far as I can tell, the environment variables were all correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some more research and testing, I finally got everything working! I had to change the formatting of the env file to be DB_CONNECTION=mysql DB_HOST=mysql_db_1 DB_DATABASE=snipeit DB_USERNAME=snipeit DB_PASSWORD=password DB_PREFIX=null DB_DUMP_PATH='/usr/bin' DB_CHARSET=utf8mb4 DB_COLLATION=utf8mb4_unicode_ci Then I got a 501 error. Looked at logs. Edited the permissions to allow www-data:www-data instead of root. Then: php artisan config:cache php artisan config:clear php artisan cache:clear Now it all works

Answer (score 0):

Use `busybox` image to diagnose it first:

`docker run --rm -it --network=mysql_default busybox`

Then in console try to ping your mysql instance: `ping mysql` or whatever your container name with mysql is defined as a service.

You may check what services are actually running on given network with:
`docker network inspect mysql_default`

There should be section named "Containers" with proper name of container with mysql - providing it is running right now.

Comment: I get a ping response using the busybox.. The docker network inspect shows the sql, adminer, and snipe-it.

Comment: Now try `docker run --rm -it --network=mysql_default mariadb /bin/bash` and run `mysql -u USERNAME -h MYSQL_HOST_NAME -pPASSWORD` to try connecting "by hand" to mysql instance. If it fails try checking in Adminer whether there is proper user and password AND host (should be `%` so you can connect from any container) for your setup.

Comment: So after some fiddling, I was able to get logged in to the db host using the above command (had to grant the permissions). However after restarting the container, I am still getting the error:  D'oh! Looks like we can't connect to your database. Please update your database settings in your .env file. Your database says: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (SQL: select 2 + 2)

Comment: So after some more research and testing, I finally got everything working! I had to change the formatting of the env file to be DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql_db_1
DB_DATABASE=snipeit
DB_USERNAME=snipeit
DB_PASSWORD=password
DB_PREFIX=null
DB_DUMP_PATH='/usr/bin'
DB_CHARSET=utf8mb4
DB_COLLATION=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
Then I got a 501 error. Looked at logs. Edited the permissions to allow www-data:www-data instead of root. Then: php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear Now it all works